# can not plot a graph using matplotlib showing error

Tags: matplotlib

Exception has occurred: ImportError
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_xcb_connect'
File "/Users/showrov/Desktop/Machine learning/Preprosessing/import_dataset.py", line 2, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import sys

print(sys.version)

data=pd.read_csv('Data_customer.csv')

print(data)

plt.plot(data[:2],data[:2])

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add reproducible test data to your post. And you only show a very limited part of the error trace.  Is line 2 the line with `import pandas as pd`?  Did you install pandas? What version of matplotlib are you using? Do you have a local file called `matplotlib.py`?

Comment: Did you google the error? Did you try this yet? https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6015

Answer (score 0):

data[:2] will return the first 2 rows. In order to plot, you need to use the columns.
Mention the column name directly like **data['columnName']** otherwise use the iloc method.
for example: **data.iloc[:, 1:2]** in order to access **2nd column**.
For more information about indexing operations, please check out [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)